# Creating input data for LRS plugin from Excel table without coordinates?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, excel

I'm working with QGIS 2.2.0. I want to add a shapefile from an excel file that has informations I want to use in the LRS plugin. The excel file has no geographic information. Every time I try to save it as a shapefile, the program saves in a diferent format that I can not use in the LRS plugin. I import the file as a text layer, with no geographic information, then I save it as shapefile, but that doesn't happen.

To use the LRS plugin, I have defined a road, made by a single line with a length. My Excel file has points with informations about specific kilometric points of that road, but don't have the coordenates, they have the length of the road matching that point.

Do I have to add the respective coordinates?

Comment: If the Excel file has no geographic information, how can you save it as a shapefile? Could you edit your question with examples of what your Excel file looks like?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this, I have exactly the same problem, a table of 'events' referenced by route/distance and a geographic line layer defined by route. I want to create points for all the events and have them placed along the route according to their distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spatial informations to obtain spatial data: the excel file doesn't contain any spatial informations, as you said.
The spatial informations should be contained in the starting xls file to get a shape file as result.

Comment: But to use the LRS plugin I don't need to have spatial information, I can use only the reference to the length of a road for exemple, isn't it? But you are telling me that a shapefile, to be created, need always to have spacial information?

Comment: yes if you want to display the dataset information as a shape file.

Answer (score 0):

For linear referencing you need two thing :

- a geographic layer with your route, each route should have M value and a unique ID
- an event table with the route ID and the relative position of the event

With the two source of data you could display the events from the table as points or lines superposed to your route layer, after doing that you will be able to export your event as geographical data.

Have a look at the [documentation of the LRS plugin](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.1.1.1/index.html) for more information